# capacitor v3 status-bar gives this error: Type 'SplashScreenPlugin' is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am running ionic 6+ with capacitor 3. I installed capacitor status-bar and splash screen like this:

```
npm install @capacitor/status-bar --save
npm install @capacitor/splash-screen --save

npx cap sync
```

then import then like this:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar, Style } from '@capacitor/status-bar';
```

followed by:

```
@NgModule({
  ..........
..........
 providers: [ StatusBar,
              SplashScreen,
             .......
             ]
```

vscode flags both the StatusBar and the SplashScreen the following error:

```
Type 'StatusBarPlugin' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
Type 'SplashScreenPlugin' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
```

I also tried switching back to using @ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx' and @ionic-native/status-bar/ngx' and even though this cleared the provider error I got a warning from ivy that these plugins need updating.

can anyone shed some light on why the this error is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to register the Plugins as providers.
Just use them in your service/components/etc.:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Badge } from '@robingenz/capacitor-badge';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-badge',
  templateUrl: './badge.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./badge.page.scss'],
})
export class BadgePage {
  constructor() {}

  public async getBadgeCount(): Promise<number> {
    const result = await Badge.get();
    return result.count;
  }
}
```

Comment: @RGe....can you point to the documentation for this?....so I remove the provider and use both in my app.component.....I got this lint error with StatusBar: Property 'styleDefault' does not exist on type 'StatusBarPlugin'....apparently the methods have also changed.

Comment: It's just plain JS, so no special documentation. Here is a working Capacitor Angular demo project: https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-plugin-demo